# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "26/4/2016" (at offset 0)

Tags: android, datepicker

I have two textview, I am using separate datepicker on textview's onclick listener,I am trying to get difference between selected dates,but I am getting following error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "26/4/2016" (at offset 0)
```

on this line

```
Date past = format.parse(enddt);
```

Following is my code can any one help me with that

```
startdates=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_entry_startdate);
        startdates.setOnClickListener(this);



        enddates=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_entry_enddate);

        enddates.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Like this way i am opening datepickers

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {




        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
             startc = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = startc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = startc.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = startc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            //dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            return  dialog;
            //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {



            startdates.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
            Log.d("month", String.valueOf(year));


        }
    }


    public static class DatePickerFragments extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {




        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
             endc = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = endc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = endc.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = endc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            return  dialog;
            //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            enddates.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
            Log.d("month", String.valueOf(year));

            difs();


        }
    }



    public static void difs()
    {


        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                    Locale.ENGLISH);

            String enddt= String.valueOf(format.parse(enddates.getText().toString()));
            Date past = format.parse(enddt);
            Date now = new Date();

            System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " milliseconds ago");
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");
        }
        catch (Exception j){
            j.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check the format of date that you are using \

Comment: Change "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" to  "dd/mm/yyyy" I think this will work fine

Comment: format that you have used if for datetime while you are only giving date to parse

Comment: how should this work without the correspondingly SimpleDateFormat String? I think some basics here are missed. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: if i use dd/mm/yyyy then it gives error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 26 00:04:00 EST 2016" (at offset 0)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is totally wrong. Use "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Comment: @Aditya Can you print the dates before parsing the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `SimpleDateFormat` string in your `difs()` method. And be sure to use the right one, as some  showed here with `MM`for the month is not absolutely correct in your case. If you  have a date like 26/4/2016, you just have to use one `M`:

```
public static void difs()
{


    try {


 //change here to dd/M/yyyy for a date like 26/4/2016
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy",
                Locale.ENGLISH);


        String enddt= String.valueOf(format.parse(enddates.getText().toString()));
        Date past = format.parse(enddt);
        Date now = new Date();

        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " milliseconds ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");
    }
    catch (Exception j){
        j.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

### EDIT:

Your question and your comments are a little bit confusing and different. For explanation, if you have a SimpleDateFormat string like:

```
Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2016
```

Your SimpleDateFormat must look like:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

That means that you have to give the exact String to parse that matches to the SimpleDateFormat. In other words, an example to pass the correct String would be:

```
Date past = format.parse("Tue Apr 26 01:20:56 EDT 2016");
```

And if you want to grab a `date string` like

```
26/4/2016
```

Your SimpleDateFormat must look like:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy",
                    Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and the String that should be formated must look like this:

```
Date past = format.parse("26/4/2016");
```

And so on...as nobody here can exactly know what String you are passing, I recommend to read the Documentation about SimpleDateFormat. It´s one of the easy described and understandable parts of the API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: i did this way  String enddt= String.valueOf(format.parse(enddates.getText().toString()));

            System.out.println("before parse"+enddt);
and i get that my dateformat is wrong in datepicker before parseTue Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2016

Comment: @Aditya : Show your log trace and print the value before you are changing the format of Date

Comment: in my previos comment i said that i was getting wrong dateformat but you dint read i think..

Comment: what you mean with ***didn´t read it*** ? Your question and your comments are different, so how should we all know what exactly is causing the error. In my edit, follow this example. Please tell us how your String that you are grabbing to parse looks like.....

Comment: i changed as per your answer so of course my output will change which i gave in comment..

Comment: :) .....glad that this is solved....I think the confusion comes from to fast comments here :) lol....

Comment: And, believe me, I also struggle with reading the API because some (or the most) are described in a very difficult, bureaucratic way. But there´s not way out of it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

your Dateformat is not correct so change the code like this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date past = df.parse(enddt);
```

Comment: if i use dd/mm/yyyy then it gives error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 26 00:04:00 EST 2016" (at offset 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your format is `new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`, but your date is `26/4/2016` which is totally different from your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Use `"dd/MM/yyyy"` instead of `"EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`

Comment: if i use dd/mm/yyyy then it gives error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 26 00:04:00 EST 2016" (at offset 0)